# WordPress RSS Feed Returning 404

Tags: wordpress, rss, http-status-code-404

We have an RSS feed (or we should have) via wordpress but it is just giving using a 404 Page Not Found on load - http://www.warrenaccess.co.uk/feed/rss2

We have tried changing back to default theme and deactivating all plugins to see if we could find an issue but it still didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My hunch is that you don't actually have any blog posts, but you are using WP as a pseudo-CMS.  From having looked at the feed and network conditions (CDN / cloud hosting can sometimes ignore feed content), things are working as they should.

Your 404 does provide some useful information about the feed:

`<lastBuildDate>Fri, 11 May 2012 10:14:42 +0000</lastBuildDate>`

Which is awhile ago, relatively speaking.  I'm guessing that your site content is all based on pages, which don't and shouldn't actually show up in RSS feeds.

To fix the problem, you'd have to make some blog posts or try this plugin or its variant:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-includes-pages/

**Edit**: turns out WP syndication setting was set to show -1 posts. Fixed by setting it > 0.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks a lot for the reply, the site uses both posts and pages although I did try the plugin you suggested but to no avail. Thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: Are you hosting this live, or is this mirrored through a CDN of some kind / origin-pull?  Friday the 11th seems like an interesting date to revisit in your operations. Any significance?

Comment: The hosting is live, the lastBuildDate is just the last time a post was edited I just edited one now so it should say today's date. Although I just checked the DNS and it appears only the www. is pointing to right the server - http://www.who.is/dns/warrenaccess.co.uk/ Could this cause an issue?

Comment: Under settings -> reading, what does "syndication feeds show the most recent" field say?  Ought to be a number > 0.

Comment: Was set to -1 no idea why, changed it and this fixed it thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I was using custom post type for my primary website content, so to include more post types use this in your functions file:

```
function customfeed_request( $request ) {
    if ( isset($request['feed']) && !isset($request['post_type']) ) {
        $request['post_type'] = array('post', 'my_custom_post_type');
    }
    return $request;
}
add_filter('request', 'customfeed_request');
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time fixing this; I hope this helps someone.

The scenario: when Permalinks is off,  I can access the RSS Feed url "/?feed=rss2" without error, but enabling the Permalinks the above returns the feed content and after this, an 404 error code. It is possible see the error code response under network browser inspection tools, like "Web Developer" plugin of Chrome.

Well, the feed client does not understand this error code and raises an exception, breaking the consumption page.

I traced the problem to the WP Super Cache. I think the cache does not generate the feed response content, but it tries to get the cache file and it don´t exist, resulting in error 404.

The simple solution, disable feed cache in "Advanced" topic of the "WP Super Cache Settings", checking "Feeds (is_feed)" options and save.

Perhaps your issue is in WP Super Cache.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar issue happen to me but perhaps the cause could be a bit different. I made a custom RSS feed. I was getting the page 404 error.

The reason is that I was not doing a flush rewrite (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules). Can do this by going to settings > permalinks and then just updating it. Then feed is available.

Was the solution for me anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your .htaccess
Turn it off by renaming it to something jibberish

If that doesn't help check your wp-config.php

Comment: Neither seemed to work I even tried a fresh copy of all the core wordpress files with no success, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What are we suppose to do if the product URLs are returning 404 i.e. **www .abc .com/product /name/feed/**  Rest everything is fine on web but only product feed URLs are 404. Also can it cause any performance issues and rank my website down?